# ¿Cómo dividir la pantalla con dos ListView?

Tags: android

Si pongo una texto, una imagen y dos listview en una  misma activity y los cargo con información desde internet, el resultado final es el texto, la imagen y un listview ocultando el otro. Para que se vean los dos he puesto todo dentro de un LinearLayout con orientación vertical y todo ello contenido en un Scrollview. Pero en los listview sólo se muestra una fila de contenido teniendo que hacer scroll dentro de él y desaprovecho espacio en la pantalla ya que por abajo me queda espacio libre.

Entonces lo que quiero sería que la mitad de la pantalla fuese un textview y una imagen y el resto dividirlo por la mitad y poner los dos listview con más información que sólo una fila.

¿Se puede hacer esto?

Comment: Agrega tu código xml y java si es que seteas alguna característica desde tu clase.

Comment: Sería buena idea que agregaras tu layout como comenta Max para dar una solución exacta, por lo pronto puedes revisar la propiedad layout_weight de las vistas con lo cual realizarías lo que preguntas.

Answer (score 3):

Aquí aplicarías definir "pesos" con la propiedad `layout_weight` en tu vista, suponiendo el siguiente ejemplo, en el cual necesitamos que nuestra vista de abajo siempre ocupe un 50% de la pantalla y este posicionado en la parte inferior, pero también necesitamos agregar otras 2 vistas, las cuales una ocupe el 30% de la pantalla y la segunda el 20%.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si tomamos en cuenta el total de la pantalla como el 1 , asignamos un valor de .50 para que siempre ocupe el 50% de la pantalla nuestra vista :

```
   <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

y asi con las demás vistas, una ocupara el 30% (asignamos .30)  y la otra el 20% (asignamos .20):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".30"
        android:text="Vista 1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".20"
        android:text="Vista 2" />

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".50"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Podemos asegurar que las vistas tendran el porcentaje especificado en la pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que dos elementos ocupen un 50% de la pantalla y los otros dos el otro 50%, puedes utilizar un LinearLayout y asignar [pesos](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) a las diferentes vistas.

De este modo podrías (por ejemplo) asignar un peso de 1 a cada elemento, lo que sumaria 4 de peso total repartiendo así un 25% de la pantalla para cada elemento.

Si la imagen y el texto no ocupan un 25% cada uno pero entre los dos ocupan un 50%, puedes encapsularlos en un layout al que asignas un peso de 2, dándole así en nuestro ejemplo el 50% del total del alto de la pantalla.

Espero haber servido de ayuda.

Saludos